# Mongoose - How can I represent "Any" type in mongoose?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have a property that can receive many type of value such as object, array or string. How can I let mongoose know that?

```
selected: {
    type: Any,
}
```

Comment: `mixed`, I think. You should refer the documentation for confirmation.